# Spring dependency injection via setter method and Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanna switch from xml based spring configuration into java-based. For constructor type injection it is easy. Example I am using:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GreetingService greetingService(GreetingDao greetingDao) {
        return new GreetingService(greetingDao);
    }

    @Bean
    public GreetingDao greetingDao() {
        return new GreetingDao();
    }
}
```

However, when I want to inject through setter method I am doing something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MeetingDao meetingDao() {
        return new MeetingDao();
    }

    @Bean
    public MeetingService meetingService(MeetingDao meetingDao) {
        MeetingService meetingService = new MeetingService();
        meetingService.setMeetingDao(meetingDao);
        return meetingService;
    }

}
```

I am not sure if this is a possible way to inject with Java-based Configuration and setter method. Unfortunately I cannot find any example (for constructor dependencies a lot of examples exists). Also I am not sure in case of Java-based configuration when should I use constructor and when setter. In Spring docs it is described that I should use constructor for required and setter for optional dependency. However, I see it as the same result for this kind of approach.
Thanks for any clarification.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you cannot change the classes themselves, you could always just not return the bean until you have injected all the values.

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfig{

    @Value("${some.value.from.properties}")
    private String someValue;

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public YourBean yourBean(TheDependency theDependency){

        YourBean bean = new YourBean();
        bean.setTheDependency(theDependency);
        bean.setSomeValue(someValue);

        return bean;
    }
}
```

Constructor injection is always preferred with class dependencies, but not always possible.
If you have access to changing the source for these services and beans you are creating, then I suggest using constructor injection and placing "@Service" on the class and "@Autowired" on the constructors.

Properties are an example of "optional" dependencies; it is common to default values and behavior if not provided. I prefer just placing the "@Value" directly on that field instead of my constructor because otherwise you might end up with WAY too many parameters. This is "setter" injection, but you don't want an actual setter method (again, not normally anyways); you only want Spring to change the value, not any of your other code.

Using "@Value" is fine if you only have one or two properties(or 3? It's not an exact science); however, if you find you have a lot of fields with "@Value" then you should use a configuration bean instead. An "@ConfigurationProperties" bean can also be treated the same way with "setter" injection, but I prefer constructor injection to be sure that at least the bean is never null, even though it's values might be.

Comment: Spring team says that constructor should be used for required dependencies and setter for optional. But to be honest I cannot see difference (cannot find real example)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My response/clarification is kind of long, so I edited my answer instead.